# can't seem to get the correct result from my pdo query althou the enterys exist and i'm getting the correct results on phpmyadmin

Tags: php, sql, pdo

on the first part i was trying to get the primary key(group_id) of my table groups of the entry i just created like so:

```
try{
 $create_group="INSERT INTO groups(group_name, group_text, dt, perm,
 group_pw) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
 $query=$link->prepare($create_group);
 $query->execute(array($group_name, $group_desc, $dt, $permission,
 $password));

 $create_group="SELECT * FROM groups WHERE group_name = ? , group_text = ? 

, dt = ? , perm = ? , group_pw = ?";
                $query=$link->prepare($create_group);
                $query->execute(array($group_name, $group_desc, $dt, $permission, $password));
                $gid=$query->fetchAll();
                if(count($gid)==0){
                    $gid="error";
                }else{
                    $gid=$gid['group_id'];
                }
                header("location: ../group.php?gid=".$gid);

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e;
            }  
     $create_group="INSERT INTO groups(group_name, group_text, dt, perm,
     group_pw) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                $query=$link->prepare($create_group);
                $query->execute(array($group_name, $group_desc, $dt,
     $permission, $password));

                $create_group="SELECT * FROM groups WHERE group_name = ? ,
                group_text = ? , dt = ? , perm = ? , group_pw = ?";
                $query=$link->prepare($create_group);
                $query->execute(array($group_name, $group_desc, $dt,
                $permission, $password));
                $gid=$query->fetchAll();
                if(count($gid)==0){
                    $gid="error";
                }else{
                    $gid=$gid['group_id'];
                }
                header("location: ../group.php?gid=".$gid);

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e;
            }
```

and then i wanted to get the whole row like so:

```
 <?php 
     if(isset($_POST['gb'])){ 
     include ("./inc/woall.inc.php");
    }elseif(isset($_POST['gi'])){ 
        $create_group="SELECT * FROM groups WHERE group_id = ?";
        $query=$link->prepare($create_group);
        $query->execute(array($_GET['gid']));
        $group_info=$query->fetchAll();
        if(count($group_info)==0){
            echo "<h2>group dosn't exist</h2>";
        }else{
    ?>
            <div>
                <?php echo $group_info['group_text']; ?>
                <?php echo $gr<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['gb'])){ 
        include ("./inc/woall.inc.php");
    }elseif(isset($_POST['gi'])){ 
        $create_group="SELECT * FROM groups WHERE group_id = ?";
        $query=$link->prepare($create_group);
        $query->execute(array($_GET['gid']));
        $group_info=$query->fetchAll();
        if(count($group_info)==0){
            echo "<h2>group dosn't exist</h2>";
        }else{
?>
            <div>
                <?php echo $group_info['group_text']; ?>
                <?php echo $group_info['dt']; ?>
                <?php echo $group_info['perm']; ?>
            </div>
<?php           
        }oup_info['dt']; ?>
                <?php echo $group_info['perm']; ?>
            </div>
    <?php           
        }
```

but i'm not getting the primary key (group_id) in the first select query i always end up getting    $gid="error;    and in the second part I'm getting results because i end up and in else i always end up getting notice: undefined index.
might it just be a problem with the table or column names?

thanks in advance

Comment: Add an auto-incremening PK to your table and use `PDO::lastInsertId` http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I do. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Undefined index means your variable is not set. It's probably something to do with the fact your if condition says:

`}elseif(isset($_POST['gi'])){`

but your database query says:

`$query->execute(array($_GET['gid']));`

Is it `gi` or `gid`? I guess you could be using both. It's a different story when it comes to is it `POST` or is it `GET` though...

Comment: its both $_POST['gi'] refers to a button and the value for $_GET['gid'] is set and thats not the line i get the error on the main error is here 
            <div>
                <?php echo $group_info['group_text']; ?>
                <?php echo $group_info['dt']; ?>
                <?php echo $group_info['perm']; ?>
            </div>

Comment: You get the error there because all your `if/else` statements evaluate false so when those lines of code are executed the variable `$group_info` is not defined. Although technically you can set `POST` and `GET` variables in the same request I would be surprised if you are

Comment: but i am evaluating with the `if/else` statment by checking `if(count($group_info)==0)` this is to check if the array is holding any values since it is we come to the `else` statement where i am using the array unless it still is containing other values.... which i think it is.... i think I'll try to rule that out for now 
and yes i am using `$_POST` and `$_GET` well the  `$_GET` is set manually by just adding  `?gid= variable` to the action.